# Can't get parameters on parent Aura from Child LWC event

Tags: aura, event

So I have this code in my LWC

```
 const passRecId = new CustomEvent( 'passrecordid', { detail : recordId });
```

and I have this code on my aura (parent)

```
getUserRecordId : function(component,event,helper){
    let param = event.getParam('recordId');
    console.log('param2', param);
},
```

the console.log is getting triggered so that means that is is actually getting received by the parent component. But the param is undefined. Anything I am doing wrong? Maybe I am just missing something out

Comment: Shouldn't you retrieve `detail`?

Comment: you mean event.detail?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your lwc

```
const passRecId = new CustomEvent( 'passrecordid', { detail : {'recordId' : recordId } });
```